# Swift3.0 Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange<Index>' to type 'Range<Index>'

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift2, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to migrate the Swift 2.3 to 3.0 and post-conversion facing this issue. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong.

#### Swift 3.0:

```
override func setValue(_ value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) {
    let uppercasedFirstCharacter = String(key.characters.first!).uppercased()
    let range = key.startIndex...key.index(key.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
    let selectorString = key.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: uppercasedFirstCharacter)

    let selector = NSSelectorFromString("set\(selectorString):")
    let responds = self.responds(to: selector)

    if !responds {
        return
    }
```

> #### Error:
>
> *let selectorString = key.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: uppercasedFirstCharacter)*
>
> ```
> Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange<Index>' (aka 'ClosedRange<String.CharacterView.Index>') to expected argument type 'Range<Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')
> ```

#### Original code: Swift 2.3

```
override func setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) {
    let uppercasedFirstCharacter = String(key.characters.first!).uppercaseString

    let range = key.startIndex...key.startIndex.advancedBy(0)
    let selectorString = key.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: uppercasedFirstCharacter)

    let selector = NSSelectorFromString("set\(selectorString):")
    let responds = self.respondsToSelector(selector)

    if !responds {
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `..<` instead of `...` for `range` to be of type `Range<Index>` instead of `ClosedRange<Index>`, in which case the call to `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(...)` wont yield an error (notice the `offsetBy` increase by `1`).

```
let range = key.startIndex..<key.index(key.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
// range is now type Range<Index>
```

Now, I might be wrong, but it seems as if you simply want the `selectorString` to be the version of `key` with the first character uppercased. An alternative method to your range solution you can e.g. use a `String` extension solution as follows:

```
extension String { 
   var firstCharacterUppercased: String {
        guard case let c = self.characters,
                   let c1 = c.first else { return self }
        return String(c1).uppercased() + String(c.dropFirst())
    }
}

/* example usage */
let key = "fooBar"
let selectorString = key.firstCharacterUppercased

print(selectorString) // FooBar
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3+

```
override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        let upperCaseFirstCharacter = String(key.characters.first!).uppercased()
        let range = key.startIndex..<key.index(key.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let selectorString = key.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: upperCaseFirstCharacter)

        let selector = NSSelectorFromString("set\(selectorString):")
        let responds = self.responds(to: selector)

        if !responds{
            return
        }
        super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]){
        super.init()
        setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
    }
```